# jQuery Datatables update inputs on checkbox change

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables

So I'm using jQuery Datatables to generate a table.
This table is used to order products, now I need to make a checkbox to update all the rows in the table but with a condition.

This is a row out of the table
(name,instock,stockmin,stockmax,order)
[image: Table example]

So upon checking the checkbox it should check

```
if($instock < $stockmin)
```

if that returns true, it should update the input by `$stockmin - $instock`

This is what I have so far.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
            var checked = $('#lowstock').is(':checked');
            if (checked && (aData[2] < aData[3])) {
                return true;
            }

            if (!checked) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

This works, it filters the right rows but the question is how to target that row and update its input.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a JSFiddle with what you've tried and some example data? I think I understand your question but I'm not sure.

Comment: This have been solved, i'll post the answer a bit later today. Thanks for wanting to help tho